# What's the difference between 一份工作 and 一家工作?

Tags: difference, measure-word

I just encountered in the HSK4 book 一份工作 while I'm accustomed to 一家工作.  Judging from Baidu ([一份工作](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E2%80%9D%E4%B8%80%E4%BB%BD%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E2%80%9C); [一家工作](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E2%80%9D%E4%B8%80%E5%AE%B6%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E2%80%9C)), both are grammatically correct and widely used.

I am unsure if they're different or not.  My guess in this case is that they're the same, but sometimes the measure word changes the meaning.

**Question**: What's the difference between 一份工作 and 一家工作?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct measure word for 工作 is 份, so 一份工作 is correct.

一家工作 you linked in is shorthand for 一家**公司**工作. In spoken, you might hear one say 我在这一家工作了很久 == 我在这一家*公司/单位*工作了很久.

Answer (score 1):

- 一份 is a proper classifier for 工作
- 一份工作 is grammatical
- 一家 is a proper classifier for 公司
- 一家工作 is not grammatical ,  一家公司 is

The examples you found about 一家工作 are mostly out of context

- [(在同一家)(工作)] = [(work at) (the same place)] - *一家 is a classifier for an establishment that employ people, e.g. 一家公司, 一家工厂 or 一家出版社 which is omitted*
- [(创立)(一家)(工作时间自由的公司)] = [(establish) (a) (company that has flexible work hours)] - *一家 is a proper classifier for 公司, not 工作*
- [(我)(上一家)(工作过的公司)] = [(the last) (company I've worked for)] - *一家 is a proper classifier for 公司, not 工作*